# Mapped network drive not visible in Explorer (Win7 x64)

Tags: windows-7, networking, hard-drive

I've not seen an answer that hits my issue on the head.  I've got one computer out of 60 that will not map one network drive.  It actually maps but never shows up in Windows Explorer. I can Y: in the run box and get to the network resource.  Reboot doesn't help.  I've used usbdeview tool to see if some usb device had taken the drive letter and was causing conflict - nope.  I logged into computer as a different user and the same issue persists.  Maps but not visible in explorer. I've even plugged a usd drive into the computer, picked the same letter that will not map, and the usb drive will not show up too.  Seems like one letter will not map on this one computer.

Help?

Comment: Check whether a group policy that [hides](http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#2650) and/or [prevents access](http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#2663) to a specific drive letter is enabled.

Comment: Thought about that, but then my other 59 machines in the same domain in the same OU would be in the same boat.

Comment: Well. I went into local policy and checked "Hide these specified drive in My Computer" and it was set to not configured.  I set it to disabled and the missing Y drive popped up in explorer.  Domain policy should override local policy so I don't know how this got f-ed up.

Comment: Probably there was a `NoDrives` registry value located at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`. Check if the issues reappears, and eventually use a monitoring tool such as [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to catch whatever is accessing the registry path mentioned before.

Comment: Check the registry hack provided here: http://superuser.com/questions/751428/mapped-network-drive-not-visible-in-explorer-win7-x64

Answer (score 1):

and31415 solution worked for me.

Probably there was a NoDrives registry value located at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer.  This worked for me, I just change the name to NoDrives_old.  Log off and on and the drive mapped for me.