# Resource Monitor not showing networked drive mapped to Z:

Tags: network-drive, resource-monitor

Running Windows 7, I am mapping my network drive to Z: with no issues. I can use the Z: drive with no problems, from the Explorer or applications. However, I noticed that a Rainmeter skin I am using to monitor the activity on the Z: drive had not been showing any read/write activity at all (hasn't for some time now). While trying to investigate, I brought up the Resource Manager and clicked on the "Disk" tab. I was surprised to see that only the C: drive showed up there.

So, while everything appears to be working correctly with the Z: drive, for some reason Windows cannot "monitor" the activity (I assume that the Rainmeter skin is obtaining its activity information from Windows). Any idea on why this might be?

A little further information: I map this drive using the IP address directly and in Windows Explorer it shows as:
[Image of "public (\192.168.1.68)(Z:)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeAWG.png)

Is it possible that the IP address being in front of the drive letter is confusing things?

Just to distinguish this issue from the more common issue where a mapped drive does not show up in Windows Explorer, my mapped network drives are completely usable by all apps, including Windows Explorer.  I can connect and disconnect them with no issues. The problem is simply that Windows does not seem to be collecting statistics for these drives (I know that it used to). This manifests itself in the Resource Monitor not showing any statistics for the drive as well as my Rainmeter monitoring skin always showing no activity, even under heavy access.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapped network drive not visible in Explorer (Win7 x64)](https://superuser.com/questions/751428/mapped-network-drive-not-visible-in-explorer-win7-x64)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate of that issue. That issue is one that I've seen numerous questions about, which is that a mapped drive doesn't show up in the Windows Explorer. My drive shows up everywhere and everything is completely usable.  I can connect and disconnect just fine. The issue is simply that the Resource Monitor does not seem to be gathering statics for these drives, like read/write per second,etc. This prevents me from monitoring the activity on my mapped network drives.

Comment: Why do you think that Resource Monitor should gather statistics for virtual drives?

Comment: If it is mapped to a drive letter, then I assume it is treated as a drive by Windows and therefore statistics gathered for it. Although my question refers to Resource Monitor, I think the statistics are actually gathered by Windows and retrieved via an API. There are all sorts of monitoring applications, Resource Monitor just being the one I figured was most familiar to people. I know in the past that this worked when I first setup up Rainmeter to monitor my Z: drive. I'm not sure when it stopped working though. Are you thinking that the statistics for a mapped drive would be found elsewhere?